# Universal make-based build system design

Tags: makefile

I am aware of tools like CMake and GNU Autotools but I'm trying to write a universal build system myself, to use for my C and C++ projects. I'll briefly explain how it works and hopefully, someone can suggest either improvements or a better design altogether.

The build system proper lives in one of the project's subdirectories (I import it as a Git submodule). The project's root directory has a wrapper makefile that defines a couple of macros and includes the main makefile from said subdirectory. That does most of the work: it follows the directory organization scheme (i.e., it outputs libraries in *lib*, binaries in *bin*, etc.), it handles automatic dependencies for the source code and the DocBook documentation, and provides the de facto standard targets: *all*, *test*, *clean*, *install*, as well as others.

Here's what a wrapper makefile that builds two binaries, foo and bar, might look like:

```
# foo-specific macros
FOO_SRC_FILES = foo1.c foo2.c foo3.c
FOO_OBJ_FILES = $(FOO_SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
FOO_BIN_FILE = foo

# bar-specific macros
BAR_SRC_FILES = bar1.c bar2.c
BAR_OBJ_FILES = $(BAR_SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
BAR_BIN_FILE = bar

# Inform the build system about them
SRC_FILES = $(FOO_SRC_FILES) $(BAR_SRC_FILES)
OBJ_FILES = R(BAR_OBJ_FILES) $(BAR_OBJ_FILES)
BIN_FILES = $(FOO_BIN_FILE) $(BAR_BIN_FILE)

# Only install the binaries. If I were building a library, I would instead
# select the "lib" and perhaps "include" directories.
INSTALL = bin
INSTALL_DIR = /usr/share

# Use the build system
include build/build.mk
```

Now here's the problem. While *build.mk* can use pattern rules to create dependency and object files, there's only one *OBJ_FILES* and only one *BIN_FILES*. So if I put a pattern rule like the following in the build system that looks like this:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN_FILES): $(OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%) $(LIB_FILES:%=$(LIB_DIR)/%) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%) -L $(LIB_DIR) $(LIB_FILES:lib%.a=-l %)
```

then *foo* would depend on and link with everything that *bar* does and vice versa. So what I end up doing is asking the user to put these rules in the wrapper makefile, even though they feel like they belong in *build.mk*:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/$(FOO_BIN_FILE): $(FOO_OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%) $(FOO_LIB_FILES:%=$(LIB_DIR)/%) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(FOO_OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%) -L $(LIB_DIR) $(FOO_LIB_FILES:lib%.a=-l %)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(BAR_BIN_FILE): $(BAR_OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%) $(BAR_LIB_FILES:%=$(LIB_DIR)/%) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(BAR_OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%) -L $(LIB_DIR) $(BAR_LIB_FILES:lib%.a=-l %)
```

The same issue applies to libraries as well, of course. The upside is that these rules can be copied and pasted almost verbatim; only the prefixes need to be changed (e.g., *FOO* or *BAR*).

Ideas to fix this include:

- Asking the user to have separate wrapper makefiles for separate things (e.g., one for *foo* and another for *bar*) but that is just terrible.
- Changing things up a little bit and then using m4 to do some preprocessing but I don't want to go through that unless a more elegant solution doesn't exist.

I would really appreciate some ideas.

PS: I know that the pattern matching expressions in the last two code samples can be replaced with text functions but those are GNU Make-specific. The style I used is more portable and is in fact on the list of additions for the next version of the POSIX standard.

Comment: So which one is it: "universal" or "for C and C++ projects"?

Answer (score 0):

I have begin to develop a similar system for my own C projects, but the logic I use does rely on some features which I believe are specific to GNU Make.

The main idea is to use a combinaison of `$(eval)` and `$(call)`, by defining the logic of the build system, and then applying to the project tree.
To do so, I have in each of my directories and subdirectories a piece of Makefile of the following form, which I name `Srcs.mk`:

```
SRC := foo.c foo_bar.c bar.c
TARGET := foo_bar
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj
```

I define a variable, which is in fact a macro, which is expanded with `$(call)` and then passed to `$(eval)`. It's defined this way:

```
define get_local_variables
include Srcs.mk
$1SRC := $(SRC)
$1SRC_DIR := $(SRC_DIR)
$1OBJ_DIR := $(OBJ_DIR)
$1TARGET := $(TARGET)
TARGET :=
SRC :=
SRC_DIR :=
OBJ_DIR :=
```

`$(call get_local_variables, $(DIR))` will expand to the above, with `$1` replaced by the content of `$(DIR)`. Then it will be treated as a Makefile fragment by `$(eval)`

This way, I fill per-directory variables for each of my directory.
I have then a handful or other rules which use this variables, using the same principles.

```
### Macros ###
obj = $(patsubst %.c,$($1OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$($1SRC))

define standard_rules
$($1TARGET): $(obj)
    $$(LINK)

$(obj): $($1OBJ_DIR)/%.o:$($1SRC_DIR)/%.c | $($1OBJ_DIR) 
    $$(COMPILE)

endef
```

The variable are computed `$(call)`, then expanded and read as makefile fragments by `$(eval)`.

(I use static pattern rules but that it not intrinsic to the idea).

The whole idea is basically to define directories as a kind of namespace, with data attached to them, and then run function over them.
My actual system is a bit more complicated, but that the whole idea.

If you have a way to emulate `$(eval)` and `$(call)` (I think these are specific to GNU make, but not sure), you could try that approach.

You can also implement non recursive make this way, by adding a `SUBDIRS` variables in each directory and running recursively the same macro which is run on the current one. But it should been done carefully, not to mess it up with the order of expansion and evaluation in make.
So `get_local_variables` need to be **evaluated** before the rest of the macros are **expanded**.

(My project is visible on my Github account if you want to take a look, under `make-build-system`. But it is far from be complete enough^).

Be aware, though, that this is quite painful to debug when things go wrong. Make (at least, GNU) basically catch the error (when there is one) on the higher `$(call)` or `$(eval)` expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed my own non-recursive build system for `GNU make`, called **prorab**, where I solved the problem you described as follows.

The approach to solve your problem is somewhat similar to what @VannTen described in his answer, except that I use a macro to clean all state variables before defining build rules for the next binary.

For example, a makefile which builds two binaries could look like this:

```
include prorab.mk

this_name := AppName
this_ldlibs += -lsomelib1
this_cxxflags += -I../src -DDEBUG
this_srcs := main1.cpp MyClass1.cpp

$(eval $(prorab-build-app))

$(eval $(prorab-clear-this-vars))

this_name := AnotherppName
this_ldlibs += -lsomelib1
this_cxxflags += -I../src -DDEBUG
this_srcs := main2.cpp MyClass2.cpp

$(eval $(prorab-build-app))
```

So, in this example it will build two binaries: `AppName` and `AnotherppName`.
As you can see the build is configured by setting a number of `this_`-prefixed variables and the calling the `$(eval $(prorab-build-app))` which expands to defining all the build, install, clean etc. rules.

Then a call to `$(eval $(prorab-clear-this-vars))` clears all `this_`-prefixed variables, so that those can be defined again from scratch for the next binary, and so on.

Also, the very first line which includes the `prorab.mk` also cleans all `this_`-prefixed variables of course, so that the makefiles can be safely included into each other.

You can read more about that build system concepts here https://github.com/cppfw/prorab/blob/master/wiki/HomePage.adoc

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, since I must write portable makefiles, I follow POSIX. Thus, I cannot use make functions, such as eval.

Comment: Well, then there is probably no elegant solution to this. Actually `GNU make` is quite portable, it exists in every linux distribution, as well as MacOS X, Windows (Cygwin). So, the question is also do you really need to support those extemely rare systems where `GNU make` is not available? You might want to reconsider your portability requirements.